# qemu simulate x86_64 can't use "virtio-gpu-gl"

Tags: qemu, qemu-device, virtio, qemu-device-backend

my qemu version is 7.1.0.

---

my qemu configure: --enable-sdl --enable-opengl --enable-virglrenderer

---

When I use qemu-system-x86_64 -machine q35, it can run with a device `virtio-gpu`. But, when I use the device `virtio-gpu-gl`, qemu tells me ERROR: qemu-system-x86_64: -device virtio-gpu-gl: opengl is not available.

---

When I add `-display sdl,gl=on`,qemu tells me ERROR: qemu-system-x86_64: ../ui/console-gl.c:105: surface_gl_update_texture: Assertion `gls' failed.

I'm expect qemu can run `virtio-gpu-gl`